# jQuery one line email form & submit to enter

Tags: jquery, email

I'm trying to solve a problem with jQuery.

[image]

Someone pastes in a link, hits enter, and it shoots to my email. I don't want any other sort of field to be required. It'd be even more amazing if after they submit the default text changes to "Suggestion sent!" or whatever message. Can anyone offer me any advice on how to best go about this?

Here's what I have in the way of HTML:

```
<form action="mailto:(myemail)" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >
<input type="text" id="youtube_link" 
    value="Paste YouTube link here & hit enter" />
</form>
```

But rather than shooting a message to my email it brings up the user's default email client. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Html ->

```
<form id="my-form" onsubmit="return false">
<input type="text" id="link" placeholder="Enter link here and press enter!" />
<div class="text"></div>
</form>
```

jQuery ->

```
$("#my-form").submit(function() {
  $value = $("link").val();

  // do something with $value

  // hide textfield
  $( "#link" ).hide();

  // update status
  $( "#my-form > .text" ).html( "Suggestion sent!" );
});
```

**UPDATE**

To actually send a mail, you will need to write server side code. And implement an ajax call from jQuery to your server script, which in turn will handle the mailing logic.

Comment: Very awesome, I genuinely appreciate the speedy response! I've updated my post with another bit of information if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting enter will already submit the form (while input has focus). You don't need any JS or sth (even submit button).

Answer (score 0):

You can use proper HTML to do this:

```
<form action="mailto:someone@somwhere.com?subject=Suggestion%20sent!" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="javascript:captureSubmit();">
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately this still isn't circumventing my issue of the browser bringing up the default email client instead of just shooting a message.